# Invantive Control - Use SUMIFS

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control, exact-online

I'm building a block where a want a formula to be put in one cell.

What i got is the following:
"=SUMIFS('Interne tarieven'!B:B,'Interne tarieven'!A:A,$C{E,.,.,^+10,.},'Interne tarieven'!C:C,**"<="&$C{E,.,.,^+4,.}**)" AS Kostprijs

Only the first criteria no problem, but the second one with the <= is the problem. Here is where i check if the datefield is before or on the same date as the data in column 5 of the given row.

If i executed it like above its saying:
That the column expression could not be replaced, and that i have to be sure that i use the right syntax.

I have tried a lot of different ways use single ', but nothing solves the problem. Or i get the error about the expression or i get the error that it isn't a valid formula.

Can some please explain how i get this to work.

Comment: What is the exact message code?

Comment: itgenuty019: Kan kolomexpressie voor veld 'Kostprijs' in blok 'urenall' niet vervangen.

Zorg er voor dat het een tekstwaarde heeft met een kolomexpressie in het formaat '$C{...}'.

Comment: Just a guess but kostprijs is a numeric field probably given this error text. When you add to_char(...) around it does that help?

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem. Getting the exact same error message.

Also changed the field to "standaard" but same outcome.

Comment: The problem is in the opperator __"<="&__ excel want is in double quote but for the SQL statement you begin the line also with "=SUMIFS...

Is there a way to escape the qoutes before and after the operator?